# How to implement and fire an event when a change occurs in a property of `T` in `List<T>` within the owning class

Tags: c#, events, collections

How to implement and fire an event when a change occurs in a property of `T` in `List<T>` within the owning class

I mean, not on the collection itself but in a property of `T`.

Is there any pattern how to do it?

**My current code**

```
public class Section
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new List<Question>();

    public int AnsweredQuestion
    {
        get
        {
            return Questions.Count(x => x.State != DeviceNodeTechStateEnum.Undefined);
        }
    }

    public int NonAnsweredQuestion
    {
        get
        {

            return Questions.Count(x => x.State == DeviceNodeTechStateEnum.Undefined);
        }
    }

    public string QuestionStats
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}", AnsweredQuestion, Questions.Count);
        }
    }
}

public class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string _note { get; set; }
    public string Note
    {
        get
        {
            return this._note;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._note)
            {
                this._note = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private DeviceNodeTechStateEnum _state { get; set; }
    public DeviceNodeTechStateEnum State
    {
        get
        {
            return this._state;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._state)
            {
                this._state = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Basically I need to know if `public DeviceNodeTechStateEnum State` has changes in `Section` class.

Comment: Based on your code what is `T` ?

Comment: I edited the wording of your question, roll back if it loses the meaning of what you intended

Comment: @KosalaW Basically I need to know if `public DeviceNodeTechStateEnum State` has changes in `Section` class.

Comment: Have you considered using [ObservableCollection<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and listening to the [ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @eitamal I dont need to check the collection state. It is a static collection. I need to know if the property of the member of the collection has been changed.

Comment: @eitamal My understanding is that ObservableCollection only notifies of changes to the collection, not items within.

Comment: @John Excatly, man. So any pattern to detect changes of property of collection' member will fit my needs. Thanks, man!

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thank you, man you got my idea exactly I was planned to express out.

Comment: There seems to be a NuGet package that might do what you want. It's called [ObservableCollectionExtended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObservableCollectionExtended/).

Comment: This is a simple thing and should not be used nugets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used this pattern before, where you basically wrap a List, extend it to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and hook into any methods that Add,Insert or Remove items from the list so that you can wire/unwire the items PropertyChanged event.

```
public class ItemPropertyChangedNotifyingList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<T> _listImplementation = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
        _listImplementation.Add(item);
    }

    private void ItemOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _listImplementation.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable) _listImplementation).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _listImplementation.ForEach(x => x.PropertyChanged -= ItemOnPropertyChanged);
        _listImplementation.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _listImplementation.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _listImplementation.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged -= ItemOnPropertyChanged;
        return _listImplementation.Remove(item);
    }

    public int Count => _listImplementation.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _listImplementation.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
        _listImplementation.Insert(index, item);
    }

   public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
        _listImplementation[index].PropertyChanged -= ItemOnPropertyChanged;
        _listImplementation.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => _listImplementation[index];
        set => _listImplementation[index] = value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

When handling the PropertyChanged events of this wrapped list, the `sender` argument will be the instance of the item that raised the event.

Comment: It is an elegant and brilliant pattern, man! Thank you so much! Let me wait for 2 days I will start bounty and you will get 500 points.

Comment: I was writing a similar reply. You beat me to it. Only thing to add is ` RemoveAt(int index)` and `RemoveAt(int index)` should unhook the property changed event too.

Comment: How did you get on with this answer? Or are you still looking for solution?

Comment: suggestions: make _listImplementation readonly, make most methods virtual, check item's not null (Add, Insert, Remove), make IsReadonly a private implementation, check bounds in this[], make ItemOnPropertyChanged protected virtual.  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() can just be coded as GetEnumerator() so it will take the public possibly virtual method instead of the inner list one. You could also implement INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: I pay my bills, bro! :)