# How to implement and fire an event when a change occurs in a property of `T` in `List<T>` within the owning class in Java

Tags: java, android

Any clue if it is possible to convert code below to Java (Android) from C#?
It is based on my prev.question 
[How to implement and fire an event when a change occurs in a property of `T` in `List<T>` within the owning class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565145/how-to-implement-and-fire-an-event-when-a-change-occurs-in-a-property-of-t-in)

```
public class ItemPropertyChangedNotifyingList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<T> _listImplementation = new List<T>();

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
            _listImplementation.Add(item);
        }

        private void ItemOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _listImplementation.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)_listImplementation).GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _listImplementation.ForEach(x => x.PropertyChanged -= ItemOnPropertyChanged);
            _listImplementation.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            return _listImplementation.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            _listImplementation.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= ItemOnPropertyChanged;
            return _listImplementation.Remove(item);
        }

        public int Count => _listImplementation.Count;

        public bool IsReadOnly => false;

        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            return _listImplementation.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
            _listImplementation.Insert(index, item);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _listImplementation.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get => _listImplementation[index];
            set => _listImplementation[index] = value;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Have we use `PropertyChangeListener` for this task? Like it is shown here.

```
public FocusManagerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        String propertyName = e.getPropertyName();
        if ("focusOwner".equals(propertyName) {
            ...
        } else if ("focusedWindow".equals(propertyName) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not very much into android but porting a C# solution to Java/Android might not be the best solution for your problem. Did you try to use a `List<Observable>`? This actually seems to do what you want.

Comment: This question is under Meta effect; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380753/how-to-handle-low-quality-questions-with-bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ported ItemPropertyChangedNotifyingList to ItemChangeList.

In code, I changed this part.

1. Used 'ArrayList' to hold elements instead of 'List` in C#
2. In `copyTo`, I used Java 8 Stream. Since you tag 'android', I used [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) to achieve same feature of copyTo.
3. Java doesn't support `get`, `set` syntax, i divide to two methods.

```
import com.annimon.stream.Stream;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemChangedList<T> {
    private List<T> _listImplementation = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<OnPropertyChangedObserver<T>> _changedObserverList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final String ITEM_ADDED = "bbed36af-0b7b-4e53-abc9-02d6a14d7f34";
    public static final String ITEM_REMOVED = "7390116e-586d-4e62-9343-5b82b0a8c6c5";

    public void add(T item) {
        sendPropertyChanged(item, ITEM_ADDED);
        _listImplementation.add(item);
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return _listImplementation.iterator();
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (T item : _listImplementation) {
            sendPropertyChanged(item, ITEM_REMOVED);
        }
        _listImplementation.clear();
    }

    public boolean contains(T item) {
        return _listImplementation.contains(item);
    }

    public void copyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) {
        // Using https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API
        _listImplementation.addAll(Stream.of(array).skip(arrayIndex).toList());

        // Traditional Java way
        // _listImplementation.addAll(Arrays.stream(array).skip(arrayIndex).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    public boolean remove(T item) {
        sendPropertyChanged(item, ITEM_REMOVED);
        return _listImplementation.remove(item);
    }

    public int count() {
        return _listImplementation.size();
    }

    public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return false;
    }

    public int indexOf(T item) {
        return _listImplementation.indexOf(item);
    }

    public void insert(int index, T item) {
        sendPropertyChanged(item, ITEM_ADDED);
        _listImplementation.add(index, item);
    }

    public void removeAt(int index) {
        _listImplementation.remove(index);
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return _listImplementation.get(index);
    }

    public void set(int index, T item) {
        _listImplementation.set(index, item);
    }

    public void addObserver(OnPropertyChangedObserver<T> observer) {
        _changedObserverList.add(observer);
    }

    public void removeObserver(OnPropertyChangedObserver<T> observer) {
        _changedObserverList.remove(observer);
    }

    public void clearObserver() {
        _changedObserverList.clear();
    }

    private void sendPropertyChanged(T item, String args) {
        for (OnPropertyChangedObserver<T> observer : _changedObserverList) {
            observer.onChanged(item, args);
        }
    }

    public interface OnPropertyChangedObserver<T> {
        void onChanged(T item, String args);
    }
}
```

Other way is extends ArrayList instead `_listImplementation`. it can be provide more functionally. Personally, I prefer this way. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/WindSekirun/49fe273ee5c1feef06e2be6610c61480)

Edit-1) Oh, i forget add args in OnPropertyChangeObserver.

Edit-2) Let Kotlin optimize this! [Gist](https://gist.github.com/WindSekirun/ece09a7291a28e248cada316dab3d9df)